# React Native multi line header title possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I was looking into supporting multiple lines (2) in the stack navigator header. I tried populating the header title using navigation options with a line break `\n` to push the contents after the line break to the next line. But instead, react native is showing elipsis `...`, may be since the total length of the title exceeds the permissible limit. Is there a way to support 2 lines in the header title, like shown below?

```
Big title
small title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

This App do this (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wibblystuff.gear)

You can see source on GitHub https://github.com/satya164/PocketGear

I don't know what exactly file is, but this project can help you :D

Comment: Looks like a custom implementation: https://github.com/satya164/PocketGear/blob/master/src/components/Appbar.js

Comment: @Rajesh also note `headerMode: none` in https://github.com/satya164/PocketGear/blob/master/src/components/Home.js#L19

Comment: I used this project as a reference and created a header for my requirements. Thanks guys!